# Spring Boot Exception Handling custom Exceptions for Database Errors?

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, error-handling, spring-data-jpa

I created multiple custom Exceptions for various Errors that could occur during runtime. For this I'm using the @ControllerAdvice annotation and a global error handler (as described here: [Spring Boot Exception Handling](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).
I also implemented constraints on the Database level (it is a SQL Server Database in case this matters) and I have one table that has two different constraints that could be thrown when inserting Data.

What I would like do do now is implement custom exceptions in Spring Boot for each constraint at the Database level, so I can give the user feedback what was wrong with the Dataset he tried to send to my Backend. Is this possible? If it is, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses the DataAccessException hierarchy which let us handle the exceptions without knowing the details of the database.

You can catch them in a controller advice and apply the logic that you want.

UPDATE:

Try to put this lines in your controller advice

```
 @ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
 @ResponseBody
 public RestApiError handle(DataAccessException e) {
   // Add your logic here 
 }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I already implemented the controller advice class and it is working fine so far for application level errors. What I'm trying to do now is hadle an exception based on the database response. I have a table with colums Id, a, b,c and a+b and b+c got a unique constraint each. I want to be able to tell the user what constraint was broken by his data so he can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jaume mentioned - Spring wraps the exception in it's own hierarchy. However it actually wraps the original exception as created by the database driver and exception is also wrapped in between if you are using JPA/Hibernate. That original exception has the data which you are interested in. As an example if I have an entity `Book` with a unique constraint on field `name` and I attempt to create two books with identical name then if I am using HSQLDB in-memory database then I get following exception hierarchy ( first one is the one at the top.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException ( from Spring)
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException ( from Hibernate)
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ( from hsqldb driver)
```

The inner most or the root cause of exception contains information about the constraint violation and the table.

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; UK_WUGRYET8MF6OI28N00X2EOC4 table: BOOK
```

You also get the `SQLState` and `VendorCode`  fields defined by JDBC which can provide info about the SQL Exception. You can use the utility program provided [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html) to extract the info

[image]

You can use below code to loop through to get the root cause of exception.

```
public static Throwable getRootException(Throwable exception){
         Throwable rootException=exception;
         while(rootException.getCause()!=null){
          rootException = rootException.getCause();
         }
         return rootException;
        }
```

So in essence you need to get the root cause of your exception in the exception handler and build appropriate response for your clients.